# Dual Boot Ubuntu in Windows 8 OEM System when USB is not detected

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, wubi, uefi

Ok... So I trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and Windows 8.1 Asus OEM on my laptop, and it DOES have UEFI BIOS. So, in accordance with the instructions, I disabled Fast Startup, SecureBoot, but I do not believe Legacy Boot is an option in my BIOS (I will double check with Asus support). So after I did that, I used UNETBOOTIN to burn a 14.04 64 bit ISO image onto an 8 GB Flash Drive via the USB 3 port (have also tried USB 2.0). I go into Advanced Startup options from in windows and choose boot a device, but the only option there is "ubuntu" from my previous failed installation (which I later removed). The USB does not appear in that menu, nor in BIOS in the Boot Order Menu (only the ubuntu entry again), and I am not sure what to do. My old laptop also does not boot off USB anymore, so must I go with VirtualBox? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use unetbootin. I've seen many reports of similar problems when people try to use it. Instead, if you've got an existing Linux (or OS X) installation, use `dd` to copy the image to the USB drive, as in:

```
sudo dd if=imagefile.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

This example assumes that `/dev/sdc` is your USB flash drive; change that detail appropriately, along with the filename for the image file.

There are `dd` ports to Windows; or you could use [Rufus,](http://rufus.akeo.ie) which seems to do a better job at creating EFI-bootable images.